# Change view template by API version on Grape and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, versioning, ruby-grape, grape-api

I am building web API with Grape gem on Ruby on Rails 4.1, with their 'version' function.

Sample code here.

```
# app/api/api.rb
class API < Grape::API
  prefix 'api'
  format :json
  formatter :json, Grape::Formatter::Rabl
  default_format :json

  mount V1::Root
end

# app/api/v1/root.rb
module V1
  class Root < Grape::API
    version 'v1'
    resource :users, rabl: "users" do
      get '/' do
        @users = User.all
      end
    end
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
mount API => "/"
```

with these code, `app/views/api/users.rabl` is used for view template  on request to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users`.

I want to use template in `app/views/api/v1` for `v1` request. Is there any way to do that ?

### current

- `/api/v1/users` -> `app/views/api/users.rabl`
- `/api/v2/users` -> `app/views/api/users.rabl`

### want

- `/api/v1/users` -> `app/views/api/v1/users.rabl`
- `/api/v2/users` -> `app/views/api/v2/users.rabl`

Comment: I looking for some great solutions, but it seems to rabl-grape gem native does not support grape versioning, maybe you can try: 'resource :users, rabl: "v1/users" do' ... Iam not sure if it will be work, cause Iam not able to test it right now..

Comment: Thanks Jan, your solution is one way to switch version of views. If there is no other solutions, I'll take this way.

Comment: Did you end up getting a result?

Comment: Yes, finally I took Jan's way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally took Jan's way.

```
resource :users, rabl: "v1/users" do
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Grape Entity:https://github.com/intridea/grape-entity

So I created a directory on v1 folder called `entities`

ex:
`api/v1/entities/token_response_entity.rb`

```
module ExampleAPI::V1::Entities
  class TokenResponseEntity < Grape::Entity
    expose :token , documentation: { type: 'string', desc: 'Token String' }
  end
end
```

So when I need to present I just need to use:

`present tokens, with: ExampleAPI::V1::Entities::TokenResponseEntity`